# Split text to get specific part?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python to pull out the country of residence that somebody has. The lines where the country is in are (address faked):

```
<HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><B>Buyer Information</B><HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000">
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0" CLASS="ta"><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD WIDTH="25%">&nbsp;Username:</TD>
<TD WIDTH="75%"><B>joedane</B>&nbsp;<A HREF="http://www.bricklink.com/feedback.asp?u=joedane">(6)</A><IMG BORDER=0 ALT="" SRC="/images/dot.gif" ALIGN="ABSMIDDLE" WIDTH="4" HEIGHT="16"></TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD>&nbsp;E-Mail:</TD><TD><A HREF="mailto:lala@lala.la">lala@lala.la</A></TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD WIDTH="25%" VALIGN="TOP">&nbsp;Name & Address:</TD>
<TD WIDTH="75%">Joe Dane
<BR>XXXX 24
<BR>12345 QWERTY
<BR>Germany</TD>
</TR></TABLE>
<HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><B>Seller Information</B><HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000">
```

I need to get that 'Germany' on the third to last row. However, the country and address will be different each time, so I need a way to pull out the country, but not depending on the address before it.

I have tried:

```
#get Shipping Destination
shippingDest = order.split('</TD></TR></TABLE><HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><B>Seller Information</B>')[0].split('<BR>')[1]
```

But it doesn't stop on the first BR it finds before the  line. Hopefully, my split concept is wrong. This should be an easy problem. Any help?

---

EDIT:

The actual code continues and after Seller information there is a similar code as in the buyer information with Germany, but with my own country. The script yields Spain, my own country. Can I somehow let it skip my country and go for the Second? Would be the one after Seller Information if you are going backwards.

This is the actual code until the end of the html. After Germany it's always the same.

```
<HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><B>Buyer Information</B><HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000">
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0" CLASS="ta"><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD WIDTH="25%">&nbsp;Username:</TD>
<TD WIDTH="75%"><B>joedane</B>&nbsp;<A HREF="http://www.bricklink.com/feedback.asp?u=joedane">(6)</A><IMG BORDER=0 ALT="" SRC="/images/dot.gif" ALIGN="ABSMIDDLE" WIDTH="4" HEIGHT="16"></TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD>&nbsp;E-Mail:</TD><TD><A HREF="mailto:lala@lala.la">lala@lala.la</A></TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD WIDTH="25%" VALIGN="TOP">&nbsp;Name & Address:</TD>
<TD WIDTH="75%">Joe Dane
<BR>XXXX 24
<BR>12345 QWERTY
<BR>Germany</TD>
</TR></TABLE>
<HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><B>Seller Information</B><HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000">
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0" CLASS="ta">
<TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD WIDTH="25%">&nbsp;Username:</TD><TD WIDTH="75%"><B>Brick_Top</B>&nbsp;<A HREF="http://www.bricklink.com/feedback.asp?u=Brick_Top">(466)</A>
<A HREF="http://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=54">
<IMG ALT="" WIDTH="16" HSPACE="3" ALIGN="ABSMIDDLE" HEIGHT="16" BORDER="0" SRC="/images/bricks/star2.png"></A>
<A HREF="http://www.bricklink.com/aboutMe.asp?u=Brick_Top">
<IMG ALT="" WIDTH="18" ALIGN="ABSMIDDLE" HEIGHT="16" BORDER="0" SRC="/images/bricks/me.png"></A></TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD>&nbsp;Store Name:</TD><TD><B>Top Bricks from Brick Top</B></TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD>&nbsp;Store Link:</TD><TD><A HREF="/store.asp?p=Brick_Top">http://www.bricklink.com/store.asp?p=Brick_Top</A></TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD>&nbsp;E-Mail:</TD><TD><A HREF="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">myemail@gmail.com</A></TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">
<TD WIDTH="25%" VALIGN="TOP">&nbsp;Name & Address:</TD>
<TD WIDTH="75%">Gerald Me
<BR>qwerty 234
<BR>Sevilla 41500
<BR>Spain</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

All I want to get is **that** Germany (the first country from the two). Many, many thanks.

---

EDIT 2.0:

Interestingly enough, I was able to do it just adding that [-5]. I don't understand it well but my guess is that it find the fifth BR from the first table.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')

country = soup.find('table').find_all('br')[-5]
print(country.find_next(text=True).string)
```

Comment: is that the last line of your table always?

Comment: @SravanKGhantasala it's not the last line, but it's always like that, and the unique line with "Seller information" on it. Can I split it back from the line with seller information, until the first BR? That would bring out what's in between **that** <BR> and **that** </TD>. Or so I hope. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use a `html` parser like [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). It finds the last `<br>` of the table and from there search next sibling including text nodes, which returns the country:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys 

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')

country = soup.find('table').find_all('br')[-1]
print(country.find_next(text=True).string)
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py htmlfile
```

That yields:

```
Germany
```

Comment: Was about to give you same solution Brick Top. Thanks Birei :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just installed BSoup and tried it for the first time. However, it yields the following error with this piece of code:   File "script.py", line 1
    for bs4 import BeautifulSoup
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @BrickTop: Did you use `for` instead of `from` or is a typo?

Comment: @Birei I've tried both, with the `for` and `from` tags. However, with the from tag (correct one) it gives me this error ` from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4` so my best guess is that I have a problem there somewhere... Thanks once again.

Comment: @BrickTop: Perhaps you are using a lower version. Look at the docs at how to fix it: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html. And here the version 4: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Dummy me, I had an error on install and dint't even notice. Now, I have a small other problem. I edited the question above to show the new one. If you can input, it would be great.

Comment: @BrickTop: I gave you a way to solve this kind of problems. Your best bet now is to learn a bit of `python` and `beautifulsoup` reading its docs. I'm not going to be modifying the code to adapt it for each new requirement or change of `xml` data. That's your work and it's good for you.

Comment: @BrickTop That's really not fair to ask of the answerer. You've got an example of how to extract data using the right tool for the job. What you need to do is find some logic that can be used to extract the item you're after and give it a go... the docs for beautifulsoup are good... give it a go first...

Comment: @Birei Completely understood, I'm reading through the docs slowly. Thanks again for the input and giving me the way.

Answer (score 1):

you may use `regular expression`

```
target_str="<HR NOSHADE SI..."

results=re.findall(r"<BR>\w*{20}</TD>", target_str)

for country in results:
   print country   //the out put will be  <BR>Germany</TD>

                   //you can do some other things 
                   //to pull Germany out of  <BR>Germany</TD>
```

Comment: Thanks @Patato. I just read further and thought it would be easier with re's rather than splits. I'll try out and update if any problems arouse.